# preg_match form input validation using an array

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate form input fields when they are not empty and display the error message on the form field that failed the validation using PHP.

I have an array made up of the name attributes used in the input fields which I want to check against the regular expression.

My PHP and HTML look something like the following (just showing one input field to make it short):

```html
<?php 

  $check_fields = array('f_name', 'm_name', 'l_name', 'st_name','city', 'state', 'zip');

foreach($check_fields as $check){
           if(!empty($check)){
                if(!preg_match('/^[\w\d\s\.]+$/', $check)) {
    // if failed, do not process the form
    // and show the error on the input field, i.e, the div with matching name on $errors[''];
}

}
}

?>


<div>
     <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
       <input id="f_name" name="f_name" type="text" />
         <div class="error_message_highlight"><?PHP echo $errors['f_name']; ?></div>
</div>
```

I know how to validate all of these input fields individually, but I have close to thousand input fields, so I want to do it in an array. I would greatly appreciate the help in achieving that. Thank You very much for your time and help.

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: You should be checking `$_POST[$check]`, not `$check` itself.

Comment: @JoelCrypto I want the 'foreach' loop to stop , once it fails the preg_match and indicate the error on the error field. Unfortunately, the way I am doing it does not work

Comment: @Barmar I tried checking that way, but could not get to show the error message. How do I show the error for a particular input field that fails the validation?

Comment: If the validation fails, set `$errors[$check] = "Error message". Later, check if `$errors` is empty. If not, display all the error messages in the `error_message_highlight` DIV.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much for the solution. It worked! I am new to this, so I cannot vote for your solution. Once again thanks a lot.